# How to add in EmEditor?

Tags: regex, csv, emeditor

I have the following data in a csv file.

```
vertical,7 day,email,fname,lname
Auto Finance,550418,550418,531194,493993
Auto Finance,104890,104890,101398,94135
Auto Finance,47684,47684,45724,42696
Auto Finance,31939,31939,30987,29514
```

I want the SUM of all those lines in a single line like this:

```
vertical,7 day,email,fname,lname
Auto Finance,1150418,950418,831194,793993
```

How would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following macro. A CSV file  must be opened in Cell selection mode in EmEditor, and all the number cells are selected before you run this macro.

```
// write sums of each column below selected cells.
if( document.CellMode ) {
    x1 = document.selection.GetTopPointX( eePosCell );
    y1 = document.selection.GetTopPointY( eePosCell );
    x2 = document.selection.GetBottomPointX( eePosCell );
    y2 = document.selection.GetBottomPointY( eePosCell );
    
    var sum = [];
    for( var x = x1; x <= x2; ++x ) {
        sum[x] = 0;
    }
    
    for( var x = x1; x <= x2; ++x ) {
        for( var y = y1; y <= y2; ++y ) {
            var s = document.GetCell( y, x, eeCellIncludeNone );
            var n = parseInt( s );
            if( !isNaN( n ) ) {
                sum[x] += n;
            }
        }
    }
    
    document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, x1, y2 );
    document.selection.LineOpen(false);
    y = y2 + 1;
    for( var x = x1; x <= x2; ++x ) {
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, x, y );
        document.selection.Text = sum[x];
    }
    document.selection.NewLine();
}
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `SumCSV.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run SumCSV.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.